# Google Drive API list all occurances of the folder

Tags: php, web-services, laravel-5, permissions, google-drive-api

I am using `Google Drive API client` for `Laravel` and I am trying to list the folders by query filters.

```
$scope = Config::get('options.gdrive_scopes');
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . base_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'gdrive_atdnj.json');

$user = Config::get('options.google_drive_user_name');
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName(Config::get('app.name'));
$client->setScopes($scope);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setSubject($user);

$service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files_to_be_uploaded = Storage::files('orders/' . $orderId);

$project_folder_filters = array(
 'fields' => 'files(id)',
 'q' => "name contains '" . $project_folder_name . "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
 'supportsAllDrives' => true,
 'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
);
 $project_folder_results =   $service->files;
 $project_folder_results = $service->files->listFiles($project_folder_filters);
 dd($project_folder_filters, count($project_folder_results->getFiles()));
```

In return I am getting only one [One returned in result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3aGq.png) occurrence of the folder where on Google Drive, there are 2 folders created with the same name [2 folders with same name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTliN.png). Thought the owner is different.
How can I all the folders by the given querystring usng google drive API?

Comment: you can only see the ones the user you are logged in as has access to try removing supportsAllDrives and includeItemsFromAllDrives

Comment: @DaImTo, when I removed the said fields, I see nothing in the results. Also, is there a way to list the files that user does not have the access to withing the same drive? Or a way that I can change the owner of all the files to service account?

Comment: you cant list what you dont have access to.  It requires access to see the files.    Have the owner of the files share the file with the service account directly though the web interface share it like you would any other user.

Comment: @DaImTo, I don't see the share option enabled for the folders in web interface :(

Comment: right click the folder go to share you can only share it if you own it

Comment: @DaImTo, this is not visible in Team Drives

Comment: IF this is gsuite then the gsuite admin needs to set up domain wide delegation for your service account.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a service account to access team drives (Gsuite) domain wide delegation needs to be set up for that service account granting it access to the Gsuite drives.

#### Reference:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)